# How do I set custom keyboard shortcuts in Unity via gconftool?

Tags: 11.04, unity, command-line, shortcuts, gconf

I have added few custom keyboard shortcuts via "keyboard shortcuts" app in unity. It used to go gconf file under /apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/ section in Ubuntu 10.10. But, I couldn't find the same in Ubuntu 11.04. How do i achieve setting custom shortcuts using gconftool or similar tool from command line ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it via "Commands" (under "General") plugin of ccsm (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`). It uses gconf backend, so you should be able to configure it from command line as usual.